# Set JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu without "install" the JDK

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk

I've just downloaded and extracted the JDK **archive**, next moving it to my `/opt` directory. Inside IntelliJ, everything is working properly. I just point the path to the JDK in the settings. But I cannot issue `java -version` command... It says that I need to "install" Java... The question is: how can I set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in Ubuntu, without actually "install" the JDK? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/path/to/jdk
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/path/to/jdk/bin
```

to your `~/.bashrc`.
After that, either reboot or apply these changes to your current shell with

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Right after I follow your suggested steps, it do not work... Then, searching in Google, I found that a also need to run source command. But now everything is OK. I think you could update your answer, to include this last step. Thank you!